# How to fetch data from firebase when we have three depth of nodes?

Tags: database, firebase

[Here is the picture of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8m2Ga.png)

Comment: Please don't be so vague. Provide all possible information you can. People are not magicians. 
What tools are you using? What frameworks? why is db in the way that it is

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in firebase documentation for [reading data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events), you can fetch data as follows

```
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("Questions")
                .child("+923067529219")
                .child("+923067529219D59IJH4ER5")
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Log.i("firebase","data fetched");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: but i want to fetch all the data....so i dont know the keys for the child nodes

Comment: then you can apply listener at parent position, and it'll return all the child keys and it's data, at which node do you want to listen data for?